# How to set Tkinter Treeview column color

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I am new to python Tkinter. Could anyone please tell me how to set color of  each column in the TreeView? I did a lot of research online but nothing came up. I know it's easy to set each row color with tag option. However, tag option is not available for column. Thank you!